# CPBarPlot with different color bars

Tags: iphone, core-plot

There is a way to have different color bars in a CPBarPlot in just one plot space?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Founded how.

In CPTBarPlotDataSource protocol there is a

```
-(CPTFill *)barFillForBarPlot:(CPTBarPlot *)barPlot recordIndex:(NSUInteger)index;
```

method that works like a charm.

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

In .h file

```
 @property (nonatomic, strong) CPTBarPlot *yourPlot1;
 @property (nonatomic, strong) CPTBarPlot *yourPlot2;
```

In .m file

```
self.yourPlot1 = [[CPTBarPlot alloc] init];
self.yourPlot1.fill = [CPTFill fillWithColor:[CPTColor colorWithComponentRed:194.0f/255.0f   green:237.0f/255.0f blue:154.0f/255.0f alpha:1.0f]];
self.yourPlot2 = [[CPTBarPlot alloc] init];
self.yourPlot2.fill = [CPTFill fillWithColor:[CPTColor colorWithComponentRed:190.0f/255.0f green:245.0f/255.0f blue:104.0f/255.0f alpha:1.0f]];
```